# gitlab-ce invitation link redirects to 127.0.0.1

Tags: git, ubuntu, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to invite people to join my project in gitlab-ce. When I send them an invitation through email it takes to (accept invite) page.

When they try to it takes them to a link that looks like this

http://127.0.0.1/invites/jh8Ks5EqpbwdPuxasuyXR_/accept

Also, when they try to go to mylab.mysite.com it asks them to login. when they are not members yet.

Comment: I'm sure you have `127.0.0.1` somewhere in gitlab's config. It must be its public IP instead.

Comment: and now it doesn't send email at all. not sure why.